# Excel VBA Macro Dropping Leading Zeros

Tags: excel, vba, automation, formatting

Several times a month, I need to manually update a Total Paid column (Column P) in an Excel sheet based on a value of a Late Fees (Column K) in the same sheet. The Total Paid column gets updated to Total Paid minus Late Fees. In the picture provided, it takes 17716.49 - 115.05 and updates Column P to 17601.44.  It is a very simple formula, but requires me to click on a new column, subtract the Late Fees value from the Total Paid value, drag the formula down the sheet so that performs the subtraction on all rows, copy and paste all of the rows that result into yet another column without the formula, copy the non-formula values and paste/overwrite them the original Total Paid column.  Each time that I do this, I need to repeat the same manual process for 18 separate .xls files.

Currently, I am using an Excel Macro that subtracts between the two columns (P - K) and updates column P with the new amount across the multiple .xls files. I have a macro-enabled button that runs and asks via a pop-up message for one of the files in the directory where the sheets are located and then performs the subtraction on all of the sheets in the folder. It overwrites each sheet as the macro runs and does not make a separate copy.  I am having trouble with leading zeros being dropped from columns D and F after the macro runs. It is causing some issues in a downstream process.

An example of a value of column D would be 070836. An example of a value of column F would be 0607636080. They are displaying as 70836 and 607636080 after the macro runs. (Please see example figure attached)

My current VBA Macro code to perform the subtraction across the sheets is:

```vb
    Option Explicit

    Sub Macro8()
    Dim myPath, ws As Worksheet, mFile$, tb As ListObject
    '---------------->
    myPath = "Select one of the workbooks to process"
    If MsgBox(myPath, vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
    myPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xl*), *.xl*", , myPath, Null, Null)
    If myPath = False Then Exit Sub
    '---------------->
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set tb = Range("tbl_Main").ListObject
    If tb.ListRows.Count > 0 Then tb.DataBodyRange.Delete xlShiftUp
    '---------------->
    myPath = Left(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\"))
    mFile = Dir(myPath & "*.xl*")
    '---------------->
    While mFile <> ""
    tb.ListRows.Add.Range(1) = myPath & mFile
    Application.StatusBar = "> " & myPath & mFile
    With Workbooks.Open(myPath & mFile).Sheets(1)
    With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp))
      .Columns("P").Value = .Parent.Evaluate(.Columns("P").Address & " - " & .Columns("K").Address)
    End With
    .Parent.Close True
    End With
    mFile = Dir
    Wend
    '---------------->
    Application.StatusBar = False
    tb.Range.Columns.AutoFit
    MsgBox "Complete."
    End
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Example Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqzd0.jpg)

Comment: Try adding a ' in front of the inserted value.

Comment: I don't see where in your code "new 'xls sheets" are created? Did you include all the relevant code?

Comment: Your description does not match your code; please make it clearer. You are not creating any sheets or adding any information except in column P, so nothing should change in the other columns. Also, please add an example of the input and output sheets to help us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you setting the `.Numberformat = "@"` of the columns you want as text before pasting values in it (if that's what you're doing)?

Comment: My apologies, as it is my first stack overflow post.  I have edited my description and have provided a screenshot of the Excel.  As the macro runs, it does not copy to new sheets, it overwrites the current files.

Comment: It still seems like you're missing some relevant code here.

Comment: This is all of the code that is shown in the 'View Code' section of the Excel Developer menu.

Comment: Ok, that might be so but do you understand our confusion here? You mention *"It overwrites each sheet as the macro runs and does not make a separate copy."* but in your code, there's no such thing going on. You open the workbook, subtract the P-column with the K-column and then close the file. There's nothing being done to any other column than P, at least not in this code.